# Resolution of absolute path in java.nio

Tags: java, java.nio.file

The documentation on [`Path.resolve(Path other)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#resolve(java.nio.file.Path)) claims that

> If the `other` parameter is an absolute path then this method trivially returns `other`.

I am puzzled: why? Is there a real use case that demonstrates this feature is handful?

I have a counter-example. Suppose we are going to copy a file from one `FileSystem` to another, and futhermore we want to preserve its path string. For instance, if the original file was */foo/bar/readme.txt* at `fs1`, the copy shall be */foo/bar/readme.txt* at `fs2`. An obvious soultion is:

```
public void copyFile(Path fs1path, FileSystem fs2) {
    Path fs2path = fs2.getRootDirectories().next();
    Path src  = fs1path.getAbsolute();
    Path dest = fs2path.resolve(src);
    Files.copy(src, dest);
}
```

Of course, it doesn't work, because `dest` comes associated with `fs1` instead of `fs2`. But the code above looks so consistent! Maybe, it's a lack of my understanding of `Path`s and its resolution? Please help me to tide over this difficulty.

Answer (score 0):

resolve method is "just" used to [join](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/pathOps.html) two paths. So if you pass a partial path(with out root), than that partial path is appended to "this" path.  If you pass an absolute path, than of course the passed-in path is returned. In your case copying fails because fs1path may not exist on the destination file system(fs2); resolve method doesn't check if the path exists or not.

Answer (score 0):

A `Path` always refers to some `FileSystem`. To use a `Path` as argument that refers to a different `FileSystem` than the `Path` used to call the method doesn't really sound like a typical use case. Thus, if an absolute `Path` is passed, the method can't append it to the `Path` called upon and just returns the parameter.

I think it would be strange to expect the functionality you described in a `Path` referring to a different `FileSystem`. I'd rather expect a `Path` to be able to normalise itself and the `FileSystem` implementation to be able to convert a representation of a path to a `Path` valid for that `FileSystem`.

I haven't quite found this implemented in Java, but maybe this snippet is about what you are looking for:

```
    final Path fs1path = fs1.getPath(fs2path.normalize().toString()
            .replace(fs2.getSeparator(), fs1.getSeparator()));
```